# Laravel 4 Package installation using composer

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I need to know how to install packages in laravel 4.

I have downloaded a bundle from github, but executing the `bundle`, I see it is deprecated in Laravel 4. Can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 17):

Just using packagist, you can go to [packagist.org](http://packagist.org) , after that just put the package name at require key in your `composer.json` on your laravel project, and that run this command , `composer update` or `compose install`

in example :

```
// composer.json
"require": {
    // default value..
    "intervention/image": "dev-master",
}
```

i hope this help

Comment: Might want to mention about dump-autoload

Answer (score 6):

Laravel 4 now uses composer to install packages.

You can add new packages to laravel via a few options on composer. One is on the command line.

```
> composer require author/package
> dev-master
```

After issuing the require command it will ask you what version to use. then run `composer update`, add the PackageServiceProvider to your `app/config/app.php`

Comment: Can you please elaborate for the absolute n00bs (on Windows)? Do I type the above in Windows Command Prompt? If yes, do I have to navigate anywhere first? Currently at `C:\Windows\system32` any clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi majidarif, Steps up to composer update is fine but how to add PackageServiceProvider to app/config/app.php ?

Answer (score 2):

First and always if you plan to use composer in your work, learn the basics of it (what is composer.json,composer.lock...)
There is excellent video on Laracasts https://laracasts.com/lessons/you-must-use-composer
 That way you can avoid problems and enjoy using this great package manager.

Next use composer dump(-autoload) command frequently and composer self-update.

If that bundle is deprecated in Laravel4 than it is deprecated and you can't use it ( unless author made some changes and adopt it for l4 )
Also bundle is a l3 specific type and in l4 we have packages.

Comment: That video cast is not free :(

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you can't execute composer commands on windows command prompt. mac/linux terminal would do but if you insist on using windows then install [this](https://www.cygwin.com/) [https://www.cygwin.com/] so you could issue unix commands